# how to rewrite it in ruby on rails way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using rails4.

```
SELECT g.name 
FROM groups g 
JOIN usergroups ug ON (ug.group_id = g.id) 
WHERE ug.id = 2
```

Using this as `find_by_sql(sql)`, but I know it's not an actual way, it fails to write it in rails query way, how to rewrite this in the ror way, then I can change all the query according to that.

**user :** has_one :usergroup

**usergroup:** belongs_to :user
           belongs_to :group

**group:** has_many :usergroups
       has_one :user, through: :usergroup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set up Rails associations; probably best to use them:

```
ug = Usergroup.find(2)
ug.group.name
```